# Packaging azure web project renames folder starting with MSBuild @ special character

Tags: visual-studio, angular, msbuild, msdeploy

Background: 
I have a web role project that hosts a web api where I also want to co-host a small angular 2 app. The project is deployed by manually packaging the corresponding azure deployment project through visual studio 2013 into *.cspkg and *.cscfg, which are uploaded to the web role through the azure management portal.
I use node and npm to resolve app dependencies locally (as pre-build step) and only want to copy the corresponding JS files as content.

Problem:
The issue I'm seeing is that the angular node module fodler starts with character @, which is a special character in MSBuild. When it is compressed into the package archive that folder gets renamed to %40angular instead of @angular. Is there a way to control this output through MSBuild configuration?

Other notes: When the web role project's content files get copied over to the obj/Release/{projName} directory of the azure deployment project, the folder has the correct name and so do the entries in the generated *.ccproj.FilesListAbsolute.txt  file. So it only gets screwed up upon creating the .cspkg archive.
As a last resort, I guess, I can add a start up task and rename the folder manually once it already deployed to azure, but it seems silly and I think there has to be a way to control this through build configuration...

Comment: To confirm, you haven't occurred any issue, what you want is to replace the output `%40` to `@` vis MSBuild?

Comment: This improper directory renaming does pose a problem since systemjs config file that does the dynamic javascript module mapping and loading references the angular folder relative path (e.g. 'node_modules/@angular') so it won't be able to find it at %40angular. But, yes, the final ask is just to control the output so it doesn't replace @ with %40 when packaging the project. Thanks!

Comment: Interestingly, after updating from 2.7 to 2.9 azure sdk I no longer see this issue. The package archive still replaces the character (I can see then when unzipping .cspkg); however, once deployed to azure the folder is correctly named @angular